# Bash скрипт на автозапуск в konsole kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

Есть bash скрипт(Выполняет некоторые операции, в том числе запускает python скрипт). Необходимо чтобы при запуске через автозагрузку скрипт запускался в терминале, этого не происходит. Скрипт запускается в фоне. Я пробовал ставить галочки "Run in terminal", но это ничего не меняет.

Comment: попробуйте так `konsole --noclose -e $SHELL -c "/путь/к/bash/скрипту/СКИРИПТ"` если сработает то уже добавляйте в автозагрузку вашего DE(КДЕ)